# compare two images in android

Tags: android, image-processing

In my application I want to capture two images using camera and then I want to compare those images.

So, how can I compare two images?

EDIT:
Compare First image is exact as second image pixel to pixel.

Thank You.

Comment: What is 'compare'? You could search for morphological similarities, color, frequency, etc etc etc

Comment: Unless you have a magic tripod, those two camera captures are _not_ going to match at all on a pixel-to-pixel basis.

Comment: Yes, @Paul-Jan is right. You should think on better ways to detect if is this from the same perspective and same object(s). Maybe you should process the 2 images, maybe a kuawara filter http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/kuwahara.html. It removes noise and keeps the edges

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** Check that the height matches, if not return false. Then, check if the width matches, and if not, return false. Then check each pixel until you find one that doesn't match. When you do, return false. If every pixel matches, return true.

**Pseudocode:**

```
bool imagesAreEqual(Image i1, Image i2)
{
    if (i1.getHeight() != i2.getHeight()) return false;
    if (i1.getWidth() != i2.getWidth()) return false;

    for (int y = 0; y < i1.getHeight(); ++y)
       for (int x = 0; x < i1.getWidth(); ++x)
            if (i1.getPixel(x, y) != i2.getPixel(x, y)) return false;

    return true;
}
```

in reality, you probably want to treat the image as a two dimensional array if you can, and just compare bytes. I don't know the Android image API, but getPixel might be slow.

**2.** maybe you convert the images in to byte64 Strings and then compare them.

**3.****OpenCV lib for Android :

**have to functions for images  compression 


**a.** `Core.absdiff()` **b.** `Core.compare()`

for more details see [comparing two images](http://groups.google.com/group/android-opencv/browse_thread/thread/101cf2c181c33f13?pli=1)

Comment: The comments on the post point out a fundamental flaw in the question, but as far as this answer goes, conceptually it's correct, but use `getPixels` and not `getPixel` as it's going to have a significant speed difference.

Comment: kabuko I'm already mention in my answer this method might be slow to match pixel to piexl

Comment: Yes, that's fine. I was just pointing out the API to use if anyone were to actually go down this route.

Answer (score 4):

Use bitmap sameAs.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#sameAs(android.graphics.Bitmap)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#sameAs%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)

Comment: >= API 12, it is not the best answer.

Comment: @TeeTracker, what would the best answer be?

Comment: looks straight and simple.  