# Android compare two images without opencv

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I want to compare two images one taken from the android camera and other from the assets folder... find out the percentage of matching between two images. I don't want to use Opencv for this, is there any code available for this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775342/compare-two-images-in-android

Comment: You can iterate through the entire Matrix of Bitmap pixels this way:
    
    int height= img1.getHeight();
    int width = img1.getWidth();
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                       img1.getPixel(x, y);
        }
        }

Now here ...

Comment: Check this question it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733020/comparing-two-images-in-android