# How to do exact match of two Images in Android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I want to do Exact match or Similar Match of Two Images Like clean Master do that for Duplicate Images. I have searched on Google And found that OpenCv Does that exactly what i want. But problem is that OpenCv Doesn't work on all Mobiles.[This is the Main Logo Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHcfN.png)

[This is the camera captured image which will then compared to original Image Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWfRI.jpg)

I also found that Compare two Image pixel by pixel. But that is also not possible because Main image has fixed pixel and each camera captured image has different pixels every time.

I also found that bitmap has method named sameAs(Bitmap b1,Bitmap b2) but it only works for that images which has same pixels and dimensions.

According to my research it is also called Augmented Reality Concept. I have tried Catchoom website. But it provides only 50 scan per month.

What i only want is Compare two images which has different pixels and different dimensions.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9775477/4494555

Comment: I have do that in app. But as i told in my question, Both image has different height and width it will always return false. Because as captured image has different width and height then of Referenced image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could implement a [Peak Signal to Boise Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio) to determine the differences between the two images. It is a simple calculation and works well in my experience.

Comment: Have you implemented in Android?? Because i m not understanding how to implement in android.