# Fetch the clicked area of image in Android

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, imageview

I am working on a Quiz app and have made it working for normal questions that will be shown in my TextView. Further I require to show user an Image (probably find the difference between two images OR find letters hidden in image) and for that, user have to click on some area of the image.

**How can I get the point where the user has clicked on the Image.**

Comment: This is one of the greatest questions i have come through in forum! Still eagerly waiting to see the answer !

Comment: Any answers will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your question can be answered from this thread,
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775342/compare-two-images-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775342/compare-two-images-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool imagesAreEqual(Image i1, Image i2)
{
    if (i1.getHeight() != i2.getHeight()) return false;
    if (i1.getWidth() != i2.getWidth()) return false;

    for (int y = 0; y < i1.getHeight(); ++y)
       for (int x = 0; x < i1.getWidth(); ++x)
            if (i1.getPixel(x, y) != i2.getPixel(x, y)) return false;

    return true;
}
```

It compares each and every pixels and returns a boolean value whether they are equal.

Refer the below thread, 
[compare two images in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775342/compare-two-images-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like,

to get point where user clicked

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                Log.e("Touch coordinates : " + String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
            }
            return true;
        }
});
```

you can follow this link to check diff between images **(COLOR and PIXEL)** https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Percentage_difference_between_images
 and
 [compare two images in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775342/compare-two-images-in-android)

Comment: Will it return same value for different screen sizes also?

Comment: it will change according to screen size

Comment: But as per his requirement, he need to compare the clicked area with the notified area(answer) in the default image. So, if the value changes for different screen sizes, how will he compare?

Comment: Is it relate to image mapping in HTML?

Comment: may not be able to compare, different images but can get x, y cordinates of image.

Comment: according to your question, to get point where user clicked, i have posted this code.

Comment: This is one of the greatest questions i have come through in forum! Still eagerly waiting to see the answer !

Comment: I have not asked this question pal