# How to compare 2 images in Android programatically?

Tags: android

I am making an app in which i need to show all duplicate photos and delete them .I want to know which is the best way to identify duplicate images from device.Please help me.

Comment: first you have to define, what is a `duplicate image`. After that you can start to build an algorithm to determine if 2 images are duplicate. Then you will just have to run this algorithm through all the images on the device.

Comment: How would i identify that images are duplicate.I want to know that technique

Comment: ok, then it is not a programming question, and this is not right place to ask it.

Comment: How would i check it programmatically. There is any algo or code please tell me

Comment: first you have to define, what exactly you want to check. Write in words, what conditions should be met to be sure that images are duplicates. This is the first and main part of the question. This part does not relate to the programming. Whether the images should have same name, or same size, or same resolution, or, or, or, or...

Comment: Look at this app. you will get what i want

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duplicatefilesremover.removeduplicatephotos

Comment: I understand what you want, but it does not explain, how you want to determine that 2 images are duplicate. Also nobody knows, how that app determines it as well.

Comment: Maybe he refers to same image, like identical. Some apps may store the same image in several places.

Comment: Yes . I want to get those images at one place. So any suggestion or code you want to recommend.

Comment: If I got that right, the only way to remove duplicates is to choose a starting location(like camera roll directory) pick an image and then start iterating through all folders and compare the picked image to every other image.

Comment: @IspasClaudiu You please download that app. I need same. what that app is doing, it scan all phone and get all duplicate images at one place.it does not choose from any directory manually

Comment: @IspasClaudiu, that's what I wrote in 1st comment. The problem is that SANJAY GUPTA can't decide, how exactly he should `compare the picked image`

Comment: @SANJAYGUPTA, just decide, how do you know if the image is a duplicate. First without programming. Example: *It should have same name, same resolution, same size*.

Comment: @SANJAYGUPTA I wasn't suggesting to pick the image manually, maybe I expressed myself not too well. What I wanted to say is to build an algorithm like Vlad suggested. What is not clear?

Comment: Same thing i want to know that 's why i have asked this question. I would i compare . if i knew why i would ask this question.

Comment: So the question should be: "How to compare 2 images in Android programatically?", rhight? Because the question title is confusing.

Comment: ok I have changed. Now what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compare two images in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775342/compare-two-images-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

As in the comments mentioned, there is different ways to compare images, such as if both images have same **file**, **id**, **size**, **resolution** or more advanced through openCV, which has numerous image manipulation functions and you can easily integrate it with android.

Otherwise, you could also look at [Bitmap class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#sameAs%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) has method "sameAs" you can use that method to compare two bitmaps. But you need to convert the image to bitmap.